# SQL query question

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has about 6 fields. I want to write a SQL statement that will return all records that do not have "England" in the country field, English in the language field & english in the comments field.

What would the sql query be like?

Comment: Do you mean records that do not have it in any of the fields, or records that do not have it in at least one of the three fields? Also, do you mean that the fields must not be exactly the strings given, or must not contain the strings given?

Comment: Can you post your table structure, layout, sample data?

Comment: must not contain those strings 
(must not contain "England" in the country field; must not contain "english" in the language field; must not contain "english" in the comments field)

Comment: @unknown - that didn't answer pcampbell's question.  Posting your table structure would be quite helpful.

Comment: I cant post the table structure. I work at a major financial institution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this and modify as necessary:

```
SELECT *
FROM SixFieldTable
WHERE Country <> 'England'
AND language <> 'english'
AND comments NOT LIKE '%english%'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know if I should use AND keyword or OR keyword
What would I use the OR keyword for?

Comment: Perhaps a grounding in Boolean logic would prove helpful.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic

Comment: Unfortunately your requirements in the comments were: (must not contain "England" in the country field; must not contain "english" in the language field; must not contain "english" in the comments field). What about uppercase "English"? Mike's answer would only work if you wanted to match EXACTLY England in Country and english in Language. What if the Country's value was North England?

Comment: OR is probably not indicated here, but basically it is for when you have two (or more) conditions, but you want to see the record if either (any) condition is true - with AND, both (all) conditions must be true for the record to be returned

Comment: Hence the prefix to "start with this and modify" - the intention is to get started with some syntax that starts to provide results - not provide a definitive answer (I hope you realize that) - yes, a grounding in boolean logic would not be a bad idea

Comment: zombat's answer points out more clearly that you can have exact inequality (<> 'England') for example, 'North England' <> 'England' or "not contains" inequality (NOT LIKE '%England%') - 'North England' *is* LIKE '%England%' - you can also have "starts with" (LIKE 'England%') and "ends with" (LIKE '%England').  Confused yet?

Answer (score 3):

Well, your question depends a lot on what DBMS you're using and what your table set up looks like.  This would be one way to do it in MySQL or TSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE country NOT LIKE '%England%' AND language NOT LIKE '%english%'
     AND comments NOT LIKE '%english%';
```

The way you word your question makes it sound like all these fields could contain a lot of text, in which case the above query would be the way to go.  However, more likely than not you'd be looking for exact matches in a real database:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE country!='England' AND language!='english'
    AND comments NOT LIKE '%english%';
```

Comment: zombat, you probably want to edit your second example, I doubt you meant language!='%english%' (accidentally included %'s?)

Comment: @Dav, % is for matching any character before and after 'english'. so yes, it is necessary.

Comment: @Dav - yeah, good catch.  I saw it just before I saw your comment.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting something like

```
select * from myTableOfMadness
where country <> 'England'
and language <> 'English'
and comments not like '%english%'
```

Not sure if you want 'and's or 'or's, or all 'not' comparisons. Your sentence structure is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions do not appear to account for possible nulls in the columns. The likes of

```
Where country <> 'England'
```

will erroneously exclude entries where Country is null, under default SQL Server connection settings.

Instead, you could try using

```
IsNull(Country, '') <> 'England'
```

Answer (score 1):

To ignore case:

```
SELECT *
FROM SixFieldTable
WHERE LOWER(Country) <> 'england' AND
LOWER(language) <> 'english' AND
LOWER(comments) NOT LIKE '%english%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Select * From table
Where Country Not Like '%England%'
 And Language Not Like '%English%'
 And comments Not Like '%English%'
```